# what is the error in android studio "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_33 has terminated."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-api-levels

here is the log file

```
2023-06-27 22:43:41,328 [1081751]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - C:\Users\laksh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_XL_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-06-27 22:43:41,369 [1081792]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - Android emulator version 32.1.13.0 (build_id 10086546) (CL:N/A)
2023-06-27 22:43:41,369 [1081792]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - Found systemPath C:\Users\laksh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\
2023-06-27 22:43:42,385 [1082808]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\laksh\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-06-27 22:43:45,705 [1086128]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel XL API 33 - Process finished with exit code 1073741845
2023-06-27 22:43:46,408 [1086831]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_XL_API_33 is online, assuming it's not
2023-06-27 22:43:51,795 [1092218]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appDebuggerSettings took 12 ms, DontShowAgainFeedbackService took 48 ms, XDebuggerSettings took 12 ms
```

trying to run virtual device in android studio

Comment: I had the same problem but fixed it by creating a new AVD of 27 API level(Oreo).I wonder why AVD api level 33 ie Tirasumi is not working

Comment: its working upto api level 28 above that i have to switch my graphics to software- GLES 2.0. don't know why?'

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

1. Create a new **AVD Device** > **Select your hardware** > **select your system image** > Change "Graphics" from **"automatic"** to **"Software GLES 2.0"**

Or

1. Created a new **pixel 5** AVD. Clicked next, and selected a system image with release name **Oreo**, and **API Level 27**.